# edit xml to get getChildHtml the right place

Tags: php, xml, magento, product

I have a module installed that add custom option to my form on the bottom of the page. that form send the information, and the drop down selections to my email.
http://www.puk-int.dk/kommunikation/psy-kopi.html
In this case city, month and date.

Now I want to move the same options up to the left in the gray box (You can se I tried do it my self) But only to show (not to be a part of the form)

I debuged and found out the dropdowns is located in ***template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml***

but only as ***getChildHtml('', true, true);?>*** code
I know it xml related when you want to get child element.

How do i move it problebly to the new place?

Thanks alot!

Comment: could you please insert screenshot images and not add a link to the issue, this will help users in future to understand the issue even if the website is not existing anymore. Moreover, it avoids people to visit your site to help you...

Comment: please share your code or reference screenshot to know what is the problem.